# External images proxy

Tags: php, image, proxy, mirror

Is there a way to proxy external images w/o downloading them at all?

My idea is to provide a script (i.e. `proxy.php`) which I could use in an `src` attribute like this:

```
<img src="http://myseconddomain.com/proxy.php?img=http://example.com/externalimage.png">
```

Comment: Why don't you just link them directly? From performance POV it's even better.

Comment: A lot of image hostings are blacklisting my domains for hotlinking abuse :) So now i'm searching for the way to trick them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to download them atleast once. Once that's done, you can cache them and serve the images off the cache. This is a subset of a more general [caching proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Caching).

Comment: The problem is that I don't need them to be served like this , because not all images will be viewed more than 1 time

Comment: You'll *have* to download them the first time. After that your application (`proxy.php`) will serve them off its local cache rather than directly from the website. My understanding is that this is *exactly* what you want. Also, you might not need to write an app. Squid can probably be configured to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about Squid.